# Poco Dynamo Register Table is returning Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, pocodynamo

On my `Startup.cs` file, I'm registering my dynamo tables the following way:

```
    private static IPocoDynamo GetPocoGynamo<TTableType>(IAmazonDynamoDB dynamoDb) => 
        new PocoDynamo(dynamoDb).RegisterTable<TTableType>();
```

This works pretty well, but sometimes the application crashes with the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> DynamoMetadataType DynamoMetadata.RegisterTable(Type type)+(DynamoMetadataType x) => { }
>
> object ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext, ServiceProviderEngineScope)
>
> object ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)

Which I resolve by redeploying the application.

All classes that register the table are being injected as Transient.

Any suggestions on why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.